# Default route for all extreme situations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-routing

In my routing I would like to have something like not found route handler.

For example I have created one mapping like

```
routes.MapRoute(
                     "default",
                     "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                     new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id="" }
             );

routes.MapRoute(
                     "Catchall",
                     "{*catchall}",
                     new { controller = "Home", action = "Lost" }
             );
```

but when user inserts address something like /one/two/three/four/bla/bla it will be cached with the Catchall mapping.

But when user inserts something that should match with default mapping, 
(like /one/two/ ,but this controller or action is not implemented)
I would want that Catchall mapping would accept this request, 
because all other mappings failed. But instead of this I get an error.

Should I override some mapping handlers to catch the exception if controller or action getting an exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that it's not the Route's responsibility to make sure that "one/two" maps to a *file*. That responsibility falls to the ViewEngine. Since "one/two" is a valid *route*, it will be chosen.

If you want to handle the error of an invalid route, what I would recommend you do is simply use the built in ErrorHandling "page" to display whatever message you would have done in the Catchall.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the best solution, but you could always be more specific on your routes:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "home and action",
    "home/index/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id="" }
);
```

... repeat for the rest of your actions ...

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "article catch all",
    "home/{article}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "ArticleSearcher", article="" }
);
```

This would attempt to match a direct action, and if no action is found, pass what would normally be the {action} part of the default route to the 'ArticleSearcher' action as an article string parameter.

The downside is having to explicitly create each controller/action route.