# asp.net mvc maproute little difference

Tags: asp.net-mvc, maproute

What is the difference between results of

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

and

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{*id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

What does "*" do, other than without it.

Comment: in the second one you got {*id}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Marking `id` with an asterisk will flag it as a "catch-all" parameter, e.g.

```
/Content/List/1 --> id = "1"

/Content/List/My/Content --> id = "My/Content"
```

However, with the following route: `"{controller}/{action}/{id}"` the second URL would not match at all.

More information on catch-all parameters on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> To handle additional segments in this manner you mark the last
>   parameter with an asterisk (*). This is referred to as a catch-all
>   parameter. A route with a catch-all parameter will also match URLs
>   that do not contain any values for the last parameter. The following
>   example shows a route pattern that matches an unknown number of
>   segments. query/{queryname}/{*queryvalues}

Answer (score 0):

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317005/default-route-for-all-extreme-situations) is a similar question. the second one is just cause it to cached with the Catchall mapping.